# UIPicker, 2 columns, update second component

Tags: ios, swift, components, uipickerview

I have a UIpicker with 2 columns. When I select a row in the first column I successfully loads data and fill column 2. However; the new data in column2 isn't shown until I click on the column. Until I click the old data still is shown although I have loaded data and made a call to reloadcomponent.

How to force an update of UIpicker so the column 2 data is shown?

Update:
It seemed that the column only were updated when I clicked on it, now I see that if I select a row in column 1 and waits 4-5 sec, the column 2 is finally updated. Weird this. It updates instantly when I click on column 2. Cant it be a simulator issue and it will work in device?

Comment: Have you tried `pickerView.reloadAllComponents`?

Comment: Yes, the data isn't shown until I click on column 2

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as per requirement
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

```
{
switch (component) 
enter code here{
            case 0:
                selectedKey = [notesToDisplayForKey objectAtIndex:row];
                  [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
                return;

            case 1:

               // selectedScale = [scaleNames objectAtIndex:row];
                if([selectedKey isEqualToString:@"UK" ])
/// use your actual stuff
```

Comment: Could you please review your code because it seems to be messed up?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggeling with this for a while. It worked, well sort of, sometimes and sometimes not.

I changed from NSURLSession.sharedSession() to fetch data from an webservice to NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest and suddenly it works without delays or aborts.

I am new to iOS & Swift but this may be useful for others?

If someone care to explain this I would be very grateful.